# Where can I find the documentation for Radiant CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

I was given the files of an app built with Radiant CMS and I want to setup a local dev environment to try it out. I don't have knowledge with Ruby on Rails or any of its frameworks so I am having a hard time setting it up. I can't find a complete documentation on the internet about Radiant CMS.

Comment: Not documentation per se, but you can find the source code at https://github.com/radiant/radiant

Comment: I am not overly familiar with Radiant CMS but a cursory search takes me to the source code and subsequently the wiki: https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki